# How to place forests beside each other

Tags: forest

I have three forests, which I want to place beside each other, I have cooked up what I want it to look like. 
Here, is the MWE for the forests:

> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{forest}
> \begin{document}
> \begin{figure}
> \begin{forest}
>     [f
>     [a][a]]
> \end{forest}    
> \begin{forest}
>     [f
>     [$q_a$ 
>     [a]]
>     [a]
>     ]
> \end{forest}    
> \begin{forest}
>     [f
>     [$q_a$
>     [a]]
>     [$q_a$
>     [a]]]
> \end{forest}
> \end{figure}
> \end{document}
> ```

[image]

Comment: @marmot I guess the package was missing, (which I have added now, thanks for noticing) other than that, it is the complete code, it compiles for me. Could you be more specific if you are having issues compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very basic way of getting something like the screen shot: a `tabular`, a few `\vcenter`s and a fake node to make the trees level up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
$\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{forest}
    [f
    [a[,no edge]][a]]
\end{forest}}}$    & $\vcenter{\hbox{$\to_\mathcal{A}$}}$ &
$\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{forest}
    [f
    [$q_a$ 
    [a]]
    [a]
    ]
\end{forest}}}$    & $\vcenter{\hbox{$\to_\mathcal{A}$}}$ &
$\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{forest}
    [f
    [$q_a$
    [a]]
    [$q_a$
    [a]]]
\end{forest}}}$
\end{tabular}
\caption{Several trees make up a forest.}
\label{fig:forest}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]